# How to pass html via a querystring?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, request.querystring

I have comments on my site and because it's its my portfolio I want code samples to be able to be placed however when I try to pass html through the querystring it will stop it because of pagevalidation.

Now I've turned it off but it wouldn't work so I decided to encode it on the client's side with javascript.

However now my query string ends up looking like this.

```
{&body=&lt%3b%2fhtml&gt%3b}
```

now because of the & body subsequently equals "".

How do i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode` to convert to and from query string encoding.

(Html on the querysting sounds a bit challenging giving the restrictions on query string lengths.)

Comment: how would you suggest passing it between pages then?

Comment: Thanks I htmlencoded and then urlencoded it using javascript then sent it as a query string. Worked then... max comment size is 250 chars and most max querystrings are 8000 so i should be alright with this method.